# Using date_select under Ransack throws NoMethodError for 'day'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, search, time, ransack

I'm trying to build a simple search form using the `Ransack gem` under rails. Though when using `date_select`, Ransack throws an `NoMethodError` for using `'day'` on a `'[2014,1,1]'` String. Why is Ransack converting the Date Object to a String?

Here's my search form

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: search_offer_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :city_cont, "Choose City" %>
    <%= f.text_field :city_cont %>

    <%= f.label :available_dates_cont, "Choose Date" %>
    <%= f.date_select :available_dates_cont %>

    <%= f.label :available_times_cont, "Choose Time" %>
    <%= f.time_select :available_times_cont %>
  </p>

  <p class="button"><%= f.submit "Search" %></p>
<% end %>
```

The fields `:available_dates` and `:available_times` contain hashes of multiple dates and times using the serializer

Thanks in advance

This is my error output:

```
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:821:in `block (2 levels) in <class:DateTimeSelector>'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:774:in `select_day'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:1025:in `block in build_selects_from_types'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:1023:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:1023:in `build_selects_from_types'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:723:in `select_date'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/date_select.rb:14:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:255:in `date_select'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb:1055:in `date_select'
app/views/offers/index_public.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_offers_index_public_html_erb__3128909028606137015_44602620'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:435:in `form_for'
ransack (1.1.0) lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb:24:in `search_form_for'
app/views/offers/index_public.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_offers_index_public_html_erb__3128909028606137015_44602620'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/Basti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
app/controllers/offers_controller.rb:52:in `index_public'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run__162092440143471620__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__174773027674768040__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you sure that ransack is the problem here? what is that `@search` thing? is it a model?

Comment: The @search 'thing' is the model provided by ransack. Anyways, I bypassed the problem by not using rails formbuilders. Used custom javascript date- & timepickers